# Work stealing queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, queue

I implemented work stealing queue inspired by Sean Parent's talk on code::dive 2016. Full implementation is [here](https://github.com/vukis/Utilities/tree/d9db16f638df24ac37a5997a6628ea8929561308). I am looking to get feedback on improvements to make code more effective and common best practices.

`TaskQueue` is thread safe task queue. It has pair of blocking `Pop/Push` methods and non-blocking ones. Non-blocking methods are used in work stealing queue thread pool. `Push` returns `std::future` object. When `m_done` flag is true tasks cannot be popped from the queue.

#### TaskQueue.h

```
#pragma once

#include <deque>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>

class TaskQueue
{
public:

    using TaskType = std::function<void()>;

    TaskQueue() = default;
    ~TaskQueue() = default;

    TaskQueue(TaskQueue&&) = default;
    TaskQueue& operator=(TaskQueue&&) = default;

    void SetDone(bool done)
    {
        {
            LockType lock{ m_mutex };
            m_done = done;
        }

        if (done)
            m_ready.notify_all();
    }

    auto IsDone() const
    {
        LockType lock{ m_mutex };
        return m_done;
    }

    auto WaitAndPop(TaskType& task)
    {
        LockType lock{ m_mutex };

        while (m_queue.empty() && !m_done)
            m_ready.wait(lock);

        if (!m_queue.empty() && !m_done)
        {
            task = std::move(m_queue.front());
            m_queue.pop_front();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    template<typename TTask>
    auto Push(TTask&& task) // -> std::future<decltype(task())>
    {
        using TaskReturnType = decltype(task());

        // std::packaged_task<> is move only type.
        // We need to wrap it in a shared_ptr:
        auto packagedTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<TaskReturnType()>>(std::forward<TTask>(task));
        auto future = packagedTask->get_future();

        {
            LockType lock{ m_mutex };
            m_queue.emplace_back([packagedTask] { (*packagedTask)(); });
        }

        m_ready.notify_one();
        return future;
    }

    auto TryPop(TaskType& task)
    {
        LockType lock{ m_mutex, std::try_to_lock };

        if (!lock || m_queue.empty() || m_done)
            return false;

        task = move(m_queue.front());
        m_queue.pop_front();
        return true;
    }

    template<typename TTask>
    auto TryPush(TTask&& task) -> std::optional<std::future<decltype(task())>>
    {
        using TaskReturnType = decltype(task());

        // std::packaged_task<void()> is not movable
        // We need to wrap it in a shared_ptr:
        auto packagedTask = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<TaskReturnType()>>(std::forward<TTask>(task));
        auto future = packagedTask->get_future();

        {
            LockType lock{ m_mutex, std::try_to_lock };

            if (!lock)
                return {};

            m_queue.emplace_back([packagedTask]() { (*packagedTask)(); });
        }

        m_ready.notify_one();
        return future;
    }

private:

    using LockType = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>;

    std::deque<TaskType> m_queue;
    bool                 m_done{ false };
    mutable std::mutex      m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_ready;

    TaskQueue(const TaskQueue&) = delete;
    TaskQueue& operator=(const TaskQueue&) = delete;
};
```

Work-stealing queue thread pool. Each thread has its own task queue. The main idea of work stealing is to `Pop/Push` tasks in queue that is not locked by another thread.

#### WorkStealingQueueThreadPool.h

```
#pragma once

#include "TaskQueue.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>

class WorkStealingQueueThreadPool
{
public:

    explicit WorkStealingQueueThreadPool(size_t threadCount = std::max(2u, std::thread::hardware_concurrency()));
    ~WorkStealingQueueThreadPool();

    template<typename TaskT>
    auto ExecuteAsync(TaskT&& task)
    {
        const auto index = m_queueIndex++;
        for (size_t n = 0; n != m_queueCount*m_tryoutCount; ++n)
        {
            auto result = m_queues[(index + n) % m_queueCount].TryPush(std::forward<TaskT>(task));

            if (result.has_value())
                return std::move(*result);
        }
        return m_queues[index % m_queueCount].Push(std::forward<TaskT>(task));
    }

private:

    void Run(size_t queueIndex);

    std::vector<TaskQueue> m_queues;
    size_t       m_queueIndex{ 0 };
    const size_t m_queueCount;
    const size_t m_tryoutCount{ 1 };

    std::vector<std::thread> m_threads;
};

WorkStealingQueueThreadPool::WorkStealingQueueThreadPool(size_t threadCount)
    : m_queues{ threadCount }
    , m_queueCount{ threadCount }
{
    for (size_t index = 0; index != threadCount; ++index)
        m_threads.emplace_back([this, index] { Run(index); });
}

WorkStealingQueueThreadPool::~WorkStealingQueueThreadPool()
{
    for (auto& queue : m_queues)
        queue.SetDone(true);

    for (auto& thread : m_threads)
        thread.join();
}

void WorkStealingQueueThreadPool::Run(size_t queueIndex)
{
    while (!m_queues[queueIndex].IsDone())
    {
        TaskQueue::TaskType task;
        for (size_t n = 0; n != m_queueCount*m_tryoutCount; ++n)
        {
            if (m_queues[(queueIndex + n) % m_queueCount].TryPop(task))
                break;
        }

        if (!task && !m_queues[queueIndex].WaitAndPop(task))
            return;

        task();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by work-stealing. Why is it different than a normal thread worker queue?

Comment: I understand it as follows. In normal task queue for each thread we have its own queue, therefore thread does pop task from it's own queue. In work stealing task queue each thread can pop tasks from any queue.

Comment: That's odd. Normally you just have one big queue and as soon as a thread finishes it's current work, it grabs a new one from the big queue. What's the advantage to the above?

Comment: Performance advantage. One big queue is locked on every `pop` by any thread in pool.

Comment: Have you measured? The lock is VERY short and contention should be minimal unless you have lots of threads.  IIRC most mutex implementations have an initial spinlock to optimise for short locks before grabbing a full mutex lock. Also you can have [lock-free queues](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/queue.html). So you wouldn't even need a mutex lock if performance is your game.

Comment: Yes, I've measured. Please have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123151/how-to-choose-approach-to-implement-task-queue). I'm going to implement lock free queue. Boost::lockfree_queue is not suited because it supports only POD types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TaskQueue

I'm not particularly fond of the name `m_done`. I would prefer it semantically inverted and called `m_enabled`. Also it looks like `m_done` is never set from inside of the queue and you could use [`std::atomic<bool>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) for it and avoid a bunch of locking when you query the queue. It seems you already handle it changing dynamically and mid processing.

This:

```
while (m_queue.empty() && !m_done)
        m_ready.wait(lock);
```

is equivalent to:

```
m_ready.wait(lock, [this](){ return m_done || !m_queue.empty(); });
```

I see that you're using `std::packaged_task` which is nice and all but be aware that there are some subtle and annoying bugs with this class and Microsoft Visual Studio compilers. Like for example here: [std::packaged_task not breaking promises on destruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762674/stdpackaged-task-not-breaking-promises-on-destruction)
.

In `TryPush` you are constructing the shared `std::packaged_task` before you get a lock. If you fail to get the lock you destroy the task. But as the `task` argument was `std::move`d into the `packaged_task`, you must no longer use `task` from the caller (`ExecuteAsync`). It is also unnecessary work. I would build the packaged task at the caller and simply take a reference to `shared_ptr` in `TryPush` to avoid the unnecessary work and the undefined behaviour you got there. Worst case is you could end up executing a moved from task.

## WorkStealingQueueThreadPool

The name is a bit convoluted and too many words. I'd look for something shorter.

The variable `m_queueCount` is useless. Remove it and simply use `m_queues.size()`.

<strike>This isn't necessary:</strike>

```
for (auto& thread : m_threads)
    thread.join();
```

because `std::thread` is automatically joined on destruction. My memory has failed me, [if the thread isn't joined on destruction `std::terminate` is called](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread).

Looking at `ExecuteAsync` here:

```
template<typename TaskT>
auto ExecuteAsync(TaskT&& task)
{
    const auto index = m_queueIndex++;
    for (size_t n = 0; n != m_queueCount*m_tryoutCount; ++n)
    {
        auto result = m_queues[(index + n) % m_queueCount].TryPush(std::forward<TaskT>(task));

        if (result.has_value())
            return std::move(*result);
    }
    return m_queues[index % m_queueCount].Push(std::forward<TaskT>(task));
}
```

There are a few problems namely that you `std::forward` the value of `task` to `TryPush`. If the universal reference of `task` has bound to an r-value reference then `std::forward` will have the same effect as `std::move` and thus `task` is not required to contain a valid task for `n!=0` and if it is added to a queue `n>0` and subsequently executed you will have undefined behaviour. You must only `std::forward` a universal reference exactly zero or one times.

## Closing remarks

In the current implementation I cannot see how this multi-queue could be more effective than a correctly implemented single queue. But I would love to be proven wrong by benchmarks with source code.

Comment: Thanks for review! I 'll fix bugs soon. Regarding `std::thread` behavior please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13984169/7010551). Regarding benchmark: you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123151/how-to-choose-approach-to-implement-task-queue). Multi-queue is almost twice faster for light weight tasks (90 ms against 180 ms). If you have any idea how comprehensive and fully correct bench-marking  can be done please let me know.

Comment: @Viktor Hmm my memory has failed me then. I could have sworn `std::thread` joined on destruction. As for your benchmark unless you show the source I cannot trust the benchmark as you might just as well have botched the implementation of any of the candidates.

Comment: @EmilyL. Many consider this nearly to be a defect in std::thread's design. See https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/925

Comment: @EmilyL. test code is [here](https://github.com/vukis/Utilities/blob/master/ThreadPool/Test.cpp).

Comment: @Viktor I optimised the code for single queue thread pool. Results [here](https://gist.github.com/EmilyBjoerk/17f2735d22636cb3a4b275387cabacad), code [here](https://github.com/EmilyBjoerk/Utilities). Note that the memory allocation tests are pretty much useless as 1) a smart compiler can remove the calls (clang does this). and 2) It's only a sys call and the memory allocation will be really fast as it so happens that there is a suitably large memory area already available after the last call. Which is why the results are so close to the empty task test, it essentially does nothing.

Comment: @Viktor Essentially what I did was that I change the queue to contain lightweight `std::unique_ptr` objects instead of heavy `std::function`s. This made the time the lock is held much shorter when you pop something of the queue. I also moved the creation of the task object to be outside of the lock. Might be possible to gain some more performance by using a lock-free queue, but I'm not certain as you need the condition variable anyway. In short: just do less work and make the lock shorter.

Comment: @Emily L. Thanks! Pointer instead of `std::function` is good idea. I tested on mu PC and see that `WorkStealingQueue` is about 10 times slower than was, do you have any idea why? Meanwhile for other queues there is no visible performance gain on my tests. I plan also to test with multiple producers i.e. push tasks from many threads.

Comment: @Viktor I changed the test code for `RandomExecutionTime` from `sleep` to actually compute something. In `sleep` the OS can use the CPU core for something else in the meantime. This isn't representative of actual work being performed so I change it. It might have affected `WorkStealingQueue` that might have unduly benefited from the cores just sleeping. But this is just speculating at this point. I tried to not modify the queue classes as much as possible.

Comment: @Emily L. We have very different results on same test cases. What OS and compiler did you use? How many cores are on your PC?

Comment: @Viktor Lets continue this [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/62541/work-stealing-queue?tab=general).